# Recursive function - Save ArrayList Java

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I have a recursive function, but I would like to add (and save) previous data in a ArrayList.

I am currently doing this but it doesn't save:

```
  private ArrayList<String> checkNextPage(String urlGoogleToken){

    ArrayList<String> listTokenFunction = new ArrayList<String>();

    try
    {
        /* I AM DOING SOME STUFF */

        if (jsonObj.has("next_page_token")){
            String next_page_token = (String) jsonObj.get("next_page_token");
            listTokenFunction.add(next_page_token); // I WANT TO SAVE THIS LIST
            String result = urlGoogleToken.split("&pagetoken=")[0];
            String urlGoogleMaps2 = result+"&pagetoken="+next_page_token; 
            checkNextPage(urlGoogleMaps2); // CALL THE FUNCTION
        } else {
            System.out.println("ELSE");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }

    return listTokenFunction;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, each recursive call to the method is creating its own `ArrayList` as a local variable. One way to solve this problem is changing the method so that it takes an (initially empty) `ArrayList` as input and fills it. Each recursive call will take the list as input and add to it.

```
private void checkNextPage(ArrayList<String> listTokenFunction, String urlGoogleToken){

   // initialize if null
   if(listTokenFunction == null) {
       listTokenFunction = new ArrayList<String>();
   }

   try
   {
       /* I AM DOING SOME STUFF */

       if (jsonObj.has("next_page_token")){
          String next_page_token = (String) jsonObj.get("next_page_token");
          listTokenFunction.add(next_page_token); // I WANT TO SAVE THIS LIST
          String result = urlGoogleToken.split("&pagetoken=")[0];
          String urlGoogleMaps2 = result+"&pagetoken="+next_page_token; 
          checkNextPage(urlGoogleMaps2, listTokenFunction); // CALL THE FUNCTION
       } else {
          System.out.println("ELSE");
       }
   } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
   }

}
```

The method can have a `void` return type since the list will be filled internally and there is no need to return it.

Answer (score 2):

You create a new ArrayList within your method. `ArrayList<String> listTokenFunction = new ArrayList<String>();`, so the 'old' list is lost and when you ad an entry, it will always be the first one. Try initializing that Arraylist outside of your method as a class variable.